# Does a NodeJS app has to be purely stateless in order for it to be replicated?

Tags: node.js, global, replication, docker-swarm

In my Node application, there are Values that the User can define. These Values, once created, can change, either from a user-triggered action or from something else, for example, a MQTT message received on the server. A Value can change very sporadically or a few times per second.

```
class Value {
  constructor(valueStore, id, name) {
    this.valueStore = valueStore;
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
  }
  // ...
}
```

Because some Values can change many times per second, I don't save the Values to MongoDB Atlas every time they change (data transfer costs are quite expensive). Instead, I have a "ValueStore", which is basically a global object where all my Values are stored with their current value. In case my app goes down, I save the contents of the ValueStore to Atlas every 5 seconds, which is much less expensive.

```
// This is a global object
class ValueStore {
  constructor() {
    this.values = [];
    this.bufferUpdateInterval = setInterval(() => {
      // Every 5s, save values in ValueStore collection
    }, VALUES_UPDATE_DB_FREQUENCY);
  }

  setValue(value) {
     this.value = value;
  }
  // ...
}
```

I haven't yet implemented zero-downtime deployment. When I update my application, I have to bring the app down. When I put it back up, I want all the Values to be initialized with the Values they had when I put the app down. So, before anything else, I have to query the collection in which I save my Values every 5 seconds in order to reinstantiate my ValueStore.

```
// When my app starts:
const initializeValueStore = async (streams, variables) => {
  const values = await Values.getLastValues(); // call to get the last known Values
  for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      const lastKnownValue = // ...
      valueStore.addValue(valueStore, values[i].id, values[i].name, lastKnownValue);
    }
  }
```

Now, I want to scale my application and implement patterns such as zero-downtime deployment, which implies replicating my app across several nodes. The more I think about it and the more I am under the impression that I won't be able to do that until I make my app stateless (i.e.: that I get rid of the ValueStore).

Am I right to think that my app should be stateless in order for it to be replicated and if so, how could I do differently what I'm currently doing with my ValueStore? Could a Redis cache come into play?

Comment: It's not required to be stateless, it's just if you have state that state has to either be replicated everywhere or available via a central store.  I wonder if you could put the value store in a local memory-based redis database that each nodejs instance had access to the same redis database.  Then, rather than access the value store from local memory, you just access it from redis.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @jfriend00! I wonder too. But say I put my ValueStore in a redis database, do I still have to save my Values once in a while to MongoDB in case redis goes down?

Comment: yes or save redis snapsots every so often.